# Identify Child Execution in Camunda

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

Have a look at this process -

[image]

When execution arrives at the gateway which is there just after the common process, how can i identify whether the execution is for `A` or `B`?

Initially both `A` and `B` are started in parallel and will follow a common process after completion.
Can these two parallel executions have different set of variables (*both inside and outside the common process*) ?

Answer (score 0):

Scoping of variables is explained in the documentation here:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/variables/

You can set variables to a specific scope, e.g. in an out data mapping or in a execution listener using a script like: `execution.setVariable("aVariable", "aValue","aSubProcess");`

A and B have their own task scope and can access the process scope (default).
You can have different set of variables (only) in different scopes. Those you could create via sub process or within the data structure you carry in the parent scope (distinguished by a key).

The fact that you do not synchronize the two branches later again indicates that they may only be in the same process definition because of the common embedded sub process. If your intention is reuse, but with different data scopes, then I would work with call activities instead. They offer globally reusable sub processes and have their own data scope. You could then also split these parallel alternatives into two independent definitions, which only make use of the same call activity.

Transient variables are an option if you want data not to be persistent and only live for the duration of the (Camunda) execution.

The example seems a bit artificial. Suggestions for the best approach are usually easier when discussing concrete business processes.